# How do I check for an open dialogue in another application?

Tags: c#, excel

I work with an application that adds values to an excel spreadsheet, sometimes however the application cannot continue because it is waiting on the excel "Would you like to save?" dialogue which shows the "An action cannot be completed because..." dialogue within the application.

I mocked up a quick console app that can be clicked to kill the excel processes whenever needed, now I'm looking to make it able to run in the background and close excel automatically when this happens.

How would I check for the specific "An action cannot be completed..." dialogue?

Edit:
I should point out that the application I am working with is supplied to me at work, I didn't make it, the program I'm making is just to help me get rid of the oversights because it is pretty poorly coded.

Comment: You can use `try {} catch{}` once before you access your excel file, and if you catch this specific exception, run your killing app. Am I making sense?

Comment: The application I'm using I didn't make myself, it's just what is supplied to me at work. It's pretty poorly coded too (no exception handling, crashing on minor exceptions, etc). So I can't actually do anything with the work application itself.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Excel Interop or more explicitly use Windows functions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1285/Calling-API-functions-using-C

My train of thought is that using Interop you can get hold of an instance of Excel (potentially) and kill, if not with the windows functions you can enumerate open applications and then do what you like with them.  Its pretty low level and hacky, but you would get what you need.

One approach maybe that once you have got an instance of the app, you would be able to identify open dialogues within its scope (maybe have to poll for this or somehow get an event waiting to handle the dialogue appearing, might be as low level as looking at the Windows Message queue for a particular hWnd or something)

Its not exact but thats my 2 penneth.